# How do I clone a PECL SVN repository?

Tags: svn, pecl, php-extensions

I'm trying to clone the [PECL OAuth](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/oauth) repo, but clicking on "SVN Instructions" in the top-right corner leads to instructions on how to clone the Github repo for PHP itself... Does any of the elders know how this used to be done in the olden age?

Comment: Amusing factoid: I just tried searching Google (30 min after posting the question), and the first result was this page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pierre Joye who answered my e-mail question, here's the way to do it:

svn co https://svn.php.net/repository/pecl/oauth

For the record, SVN doesn't allow cloning proper the way git does, so what you're doing above is just checking out a "dead" copy of the current version of the code (whatever "current" might mean at the moment you execute that).